# cannot compile wxwidgets project on mac OSX mavericks

Tags: c++, macos, netbeans, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I'm working on porting across an application to the MAC OSX (Mavericks). I have installed wxWidgets and the following two commands successfully return output from the terminal.

```
wx-config --libs
```

Gives the following output.

```
-L/usr/local/lib   -framework IOKit -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework AudioToolbox -framework System -framework OpenGL /usr/local/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.a -framework WebKit -lwxregexu-3.0 -lwxtiff-3.0 -lwxjpeg-3.0 -lwxpng-3.0 -lz -lpthread -liconv
```

and

```
wx-config --cxxflags
```

Gives the following output.

```
-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-static-3.0 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__WXMAC__ -D__WXOSX__ -D__WXOSX_COCOA__
```

However, I tried to compile a basic wxWigets project using code blocks and netbeans. I followed numerous tutorials, but every time I build my project I get the following compile error.

"fatal error: 'wx/setup.h' file not found

I have added the following settings to the code blocks (and tried netbeans) IDE:

- Compiler Settings -> Other options == `wx-config --cxxflags`
- Linker Settings -> Other linker settings == `wx-config --libs`

but I just can't get my widgets project to build :(

can anyone please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you have actually checked that `wx/setup.h` actually exists under one of the two added include directories? Perhaps it is `setup.h` with those paths?

Comment: Hi Oliver, yes I checked all of its locations using find ./* -name "setup.h"
./build/osx/setup/cocoa/include/wx/setup.h
./build-release/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.0/wx/setup.h
./include/msvc/wx/setup.h
./include/wx/android/setup.h
./include/wx/gtk/setup.h
./include/wx/motif/setup.h
./include/wx/msw/setup.h
./include/wx/msw/wince/setup.h
./include/wx/os2/setup.h
./include/wx/osx/setup.h
./include/wx/univ/setup.h,, however I included the one from the parent directory "include/wx/setup.h'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see only two possible explanations:

1. You didn't install wxWidgets using `make install`, i.e. there is no actual `wx/setup.h` under the directory output by your `wx-config --cxxflags`.
2. Your IDE doesn't run commands in its settings (BTW, I assume you did put `wx-config --cxxflags` inside the backticks). In this case you need to copy and paste the actual output instead of using `wx-config` directly.